# dbDelta isn't altering the table

Tags: php, mysqli, wordpress

I'm trying to add a field Order to my tables:

```
$tables = array(Gun => 6,Color => 2,Holster => 2,Canter => 1,Hand => 1);
foreach($tables as $key => $val) {
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'GunInventory'.$key;
    $sql = "CREATE TABLE $table_name (
            GunInventory".$key."Id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
            Name varchar(200) NOT NULL,
            Value char(".$val.") NOT NULL,
            Price decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
            Order INT NOT NULL,
            UNIQUE KEY  GunInventory".$key."Id (GunInventory".$key."Id)
        );";
    dbDelta($sql);
}
```

The issue is the field Order is not being created on my tables, I've tried deleting the field from the tables and reinstalling the plug-in and my tables stay the same.  The script will though create the tables.

I tried turning on debug and I don't get any errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Order` is a reserved word.

List of all reserved words:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/reserved-words.html

Answer (score 0):

`ORDER` is a reserved keyword in MYSQL. Either escape it using backticks (`) or choose a different name. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23446377/syntax-error-due-to-using-a-reserved-word-as-a-table-or-column-name-in-mysql) for more information.

Also you should have a warning on your page if you enable error reporting unless those keys in your array are constants.

> Notice: Use of undefined constant Gun - assumed 'Gun' in ...
>   Notice: Use of undefined constant Color - assumed 'Color' in ...
>   etc

http://3v4l.org/8PLuh

The reason it works is that those keys are being converted by PHP, but [you should really quote them](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) and [enable error reporting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php).

Answer (score 0):

`Order` is a `mysql` reserved keyword. Its supposed not to be used.

Your array definition seems to be not perfect. You are assigning keys as constants. That is not a good practice.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

```
$tables = array(Gun => 6,Color => 2,Holster => 2,Canter => 1,Hand => 1);
```

should be

```
$tables = array("Gun" => 6,"Color" => 2,"Holster" => 2,"Canter" => 1,"Hand" => 1);
```